# How to get rid of label used but not defined

Tags: c++, sql, c, db2, embedded-sql

I'm trying to print the rows of a table in embedded sql.  I have this code where publication is the table and pubid is the attribute.  I tried this:

```
    EXEC SQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT pubid FROM publication;
    EXEC SQL OPEN C1;
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND GOTO close_c1;
    for(;;) {
        EXEC SQL FETCH C1 INTO :pubid;
        cout<<pubid<<endl;
    }
    close_c1:
    EXEC SQL CLOSE C1;
```

The compiler gives me this error: error: label 'close_c1' used but not defined.
How do I fix this?

Comment: This is really  a question about your embedded SQL processor - which one are you using?

Comment: I suspect that your WHENEVER statement is not, when processed emitting a C++ `goto` statement. Use of embedded SQL is pretty rare these days, so you may be better off asking on a DB2-specific site.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing...
Put the WHENEVER line first in your embedded sql sequence.

From "SQL Reference Volume 2":

> WHENEVER
>   .....
>   Note:
>   .....
>   Every executable SQL statement in a program is within the scope of one implicit or >explicit WHENEVER statement of each type.
>   The scope of a WHENEVER statement is related to the listing sequence of the statements in >the program, not their execution sequence.